# How to make Windows form applications Responsive to multiple screen resolutions?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created an Application in Visual Studio 2015 using C# as a P.L. I created it in my laptop whose resolution is 1920 * 1080 (as recommended). It runs smoothly on may laptop, the designs are meant to be as expected. But when I try to run it to another any screen resolution it just zoomed out and the designs, windows form components are not visible, inshort the GUI got crashed. I don't used any of those Flowlayout panel. Is there any setting or configurations on my project that i need to do to fix my problem ?

Comment: If this is not duplicate, some code would be appreciated.

Comment: At the moment the question is too broad without knowing any more information. Please paste some code as to what you have tried.

Comment: without any specific information, the only this that might help you is to try `this.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;`

Comment: it would help to see your code and generated output

Answer (score 0):

You may set the application windows form size to maximized so that it will fit in all resolutions by Set the System.Windows.Forms.Form.WindowState to FormWindowState.Maximized and then used flow layout/dock combinations to handle manual resizing

[Please refer this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tlht6urrb5A)